# Reading each column of CSV File as a key of dictionary

Tags: python, database, dictionary

I am working with googlemaps API with python and would like to read a csv file containing LOCATIONID, LOCATION, X, Y, LAT, LNG, REF, ID with each of those as a dictionary key

Excerpt from Data Set

```
ChIJWzKeTARawokRjoqe_C9poOA,THEGIRLSOUTFITS,0,17,40.71380629999999,-74.0222972,dc1885d8c12ac669e9de3a73fedfb08c40deefd3,CmRSAAAA4Mvy3PVnmnYQKIZg-VX9-UrnrhlwOs7YFeY40gdXw1JfuUeEZndlhWxoIdI2K0nt1voCQDg2mqUVKV6EBgOKMTrHjDsMHOy7MJYBCUWguzLroifP1UMWTYSfUJD6E6sMEhB3psbJCGcDh5iS1PHyX4k5GhRBXigoOyADpURVG3NG2bIqXJ2i_g
ChIJDaBbDPlZwokRuHXkJGK9ER0,NYNJ State Line,0,29,40.7245721,-74.02168689999999,3d2cfc0a35b583760187c2369bb957b5a8cd9755,CmRRAAAAN25LD8IWAiu8CAIFM2eMS7eJVReV_UHzmR6sbaRkhDlJgiX-wK0Xlb85hC1qmDkarwQrGoM2u60zfSMr1MxcyzMAg3UDgL6nYwwu3WgG1aNlbpiqR2HlLFlK5XhimqI4EhDrfqXHOxKeztoT01Aicp3hGhSETo6Pj7gTk-dajA0RWco1djlrVA
ChIJQX6hfdlZwokRoCdPrD-8wSY,Shipyard Marina,0,59,40.751581,-74.021287,5f5e1aa75a39ce1880085d5094694a9ceda1ff43,CmRRAAAAp_VV6L2SQgnjC_TeMYRe_m2EYyjo_IdAOUqSeuRM9kbEMHSyguWco9jDV6rdYxk5s1E5s21BX0P7flWfK2LCegcKi1m_AOp2LuYtuzv0ql4-Jeq6-yx50Z180J9U4nrHEhAihnIm2i8MWwk7ATToiLBgGhR-w02BFnO9EGniCms-XWq00VrGOg
ChIJi3MPPNNZwokRDu8nE0ldrwk,Lincoln Harbor,0,68,40.759708,-74.02225,a3192a26d0a5a779da702a7f871612992e26f606,CmRRAAAAGcYQNoc-WgRCwh3rlBzeEmlG_XQgk_coHa4qUpzWU_9DiDWnU8eLjhInrZqpR7nKibXc0dcZIYiZEb-ehKvIrF6OfbLGrpmbf47YNaofAebceKirPZ_g6jMsc-_dcITaEhAKqkWagpXbgd3CcQf8Rtz-GhQtzlAGJlP7gOzV2KfXRGFIF2ZbAA
ChIJq35iOdNZwokRKvT9_KFP8jg,Lincoln Harbor,0,68,40.75984079999999,-74.0223211,38ea8de2bbf6d8a710bec3104d180d71b3d00735,CmRRAAAASNnGG2MHHIDGcXfgH-8iWUQOEahJdMZz6dy24azZrqyXqEtMb_yP1MJRGMV6Cp6lX05MgU2vNIfHcOGBfXiG0yWU7Qe0-t9_Uhm7JxNuAOEge9ZaCwNlrtxuxr8xSYsJEhAkL9vA29DV4nReD4e85D1TGhTbZYRfvNNRZi5a3NMUA0gyMYoR_A
ChIJ07hkOtNZwokRfY7FzKrxTkA,852858 Harbor Blvd,0,68,40.7599265,-74.02213569999999,29cfd2338edc10f94f5464b2fe152ab7bab3fca6,CmRbAAAAdlTDQx7qWhNnvgDQ_1afttKRpJ_MzBULrJLNX0TFEwpvKTjCvCZoXfV1F0A_diKH5D8qDjjucrjUC3gV8iVxqOYoHRGYwifE2FSiVycUrjunQxiDYAd-C6Q7QOqswAomEhAewuH-Q09vSAW_hNbQ0AUOGhQqRXCRrgxc6EAl2xRv1Z73M4MMug
ChIJnYuB1ixYwokR3w26K1mr3JQ,1500 Harbor Blvd,0,69,40.7609258,-74.02135559999999,ed57711af76a2534406a70f21d8a7119170b0f72,CmRbAAAAbPsHkeqeX3cx5MdED0Ao6ic0PE56xhGMdda0zXolIU7KsPmgPbT1CjXfyZ0p4ws_GYgdORZB3qP0idFvWBtMpdYpXCq0VknITsvfAoNfwYXoccYGsP7QvfpBPb1oTnywEhDwyrKX9JiQkYx9YaIXhkOwGhRCtFkL2futi7BkUxo_dMYEtsWVWA
ChIJk7Y29CxYwokRLcD4dsTPCCM,800816 Waterfront Terrace,0,71,40.7629756,-74.0223474,727cf2af87d28ec3a45f11e76e0746acfbec03b0,CmRbAAAAzgEUAIfexip_ePX2VQ29-iZMDPe-5RA4aGhFRoDkEGHrTaUON7ZGyn1r16erRSWIAhESFzycoG4Rwuw4OijSlLjKfK3_HCvC4fkrX-d6I7g7ffkIotwc1KK77UkHPMz-EhBoESHGx4Ke3H9y6XfDt9iaGhSGqEI5BmtpMu4URYwFmrT-2npHWQ
ChIJsZ2B5CxYwokRL8NrRMKxD9Q,Estuary Marketplace,0,71,40.7622809,-74.021577,1b6c2bd55b1bbabe3aac0d1eb2153e812c1026fd,CmRSAAAAO_HAcE9pNnA6r0FDp1eVsfS6jVn31DxU_JhcZNACGz9kfI5xOPjTbgM77JhJLxZPJqLgO_AnNXIIyEQV_wqO5Pr-YWJaIyhCEYA8Ene36VXgQ_90NMQwa_HNJJnWywkpEhBYQL6JbpsO0FJcOawnw5-2GhRE_QU6uh-cP-RKArGSyfEE2cxL3A
ChIJ64dzUNRZwokRIHBPnvi-eJs,Estuary Apartments,0,71,40.76240009999999,-74.0216088,8219ad9d883d8891a651bc35ff7bf7abe7c7b72a,CmRSAAAA7t8RT2MVUpaxNWBPItFU3pTQwNqXDuRY28GxZ_cywaLqOFIJ7taeXDHvGg19Y0MoIerm94HrD0iZQ_iIyoUrCKueeUETgHUGf8LQJMl9mqu784B5iIIXdf9-YrylAFJ9EhCvaowPZkGZvaEVLENy8fywGhRSEtZOm86qEyOCksoFWNJp9L_daw
ChIJWexh_9hZwokRgU6sf8pvbUg,Hoboken Weehawken Notary Public  Dorian Cattani,0,71,40.762501,-74.021528,11be9c0505e8db6a7fcaea5fd4003d336b8667f2,CmRRAAAA9hteDDXN0TehPTxfnx6LxRjZTVHZOyOgbE1GJ42XOzB2v6htFgfliFz39e6llMHSlqvFS3uBiIKuH9bNu9qIfeSD8LlrSW5UXKP4U7sN-Zi1-IWH5QJw5S2hQCZHaNfeEhAT4Y9Q2hC0uG0vVi7CJPuVGhQPb5J4VpGisRfvRfiqEyPgTR8F5w
ChIJRaQT-CxYwokRlEhCGnjf6fs,EcoPure Home Cleaning Service Weehawken,0,72,40.76302460000001,-74.0218549,33800368abbf808a39da3e805c685b245e5baac4,CmRSAAAAyod24y6jY17fcd2b2mk6qgIoN_KWOCNxEN1zDniW9n7RHoWTm-MPXFN6N77XwYzORC-WarFmyP9jULhochuKcXcYP2y2ni7SWFviXVXOBtxvYVlHmfsyHctEvBy_GxKbEhB5ihU8my5kq4lQpQrwGIrQGhT-0cYHqRnMImt55xhU7CBDPPlA1w
ChIJFU-XRyxYwokRo5Do2LLO_mE,New Jersey 495,0,73,40.76429109999999,-74.0220365,23e5baf02ae51b7aeaf94efa56624c064bdbb456,CmRbAAAA_30BmNHIeCFJ7SVhLHWIbSa8llsfKQfYpVRC8X0feMrRlQ9ih9_vKtBfq-KRC6lcagEYQCBRdCfDob2divgzQEbrVkc9dR4v3oIfdyc5l9mlRyTnl1fOBxSeR8xMz78sEhD8FAIlIOza3aIMvqsdfjzrGhTj2R00Cv-lzmKIFEwLumKKd8g1cQ
```

The current code I'm trying:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as rdm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math as m

data = np.genfromtxt('PlacesFinalNew.csv', delimiter = ',')
size = int(data.size/8)

dict = {'LOCATIONID':[], 'LOCATION':[], 'X':[],'Y':[],'LAT':[],'LNG':[],'ID':[],'REF':[]}
for i in range(size):
    dict['LOCATIONID'].append(data[i][0])
    dict['LOCATION'].append(data[i][1])
    dict['X'].append(data[i][2])
    dict['Y'].append(data[i][3])
    dict['LAT'].append(data[i][4])
    dict['LNG'].append(data[i][5])
    dict['ID'].append(data[i][6])
    dict['REF'].append(data[i][7])
```

This works for every key except for Location. When I print out dict['LOCATION'] I get a list of nan. Could someone please point out the problem to me?

Comment: Can you provide sample csv?

Comment: I guess that Location is a string while the other fields are numeric so you should probably define the dtype. See example in numpy documentation - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html. `>>> s = StringIO("1,1.3,abcde")
>>> data = np.genfromtxt(s, dtype=[('myint','i8'),('myfloat','f8'),
... ('mystring','S5')], delimiter=",")`

Comment: Welcome to SO. We don't know what kind of data you are dealing with. Please include a sample dataset as part of a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your CSV file contain Header name, then just by reading csv which will create pandas DataFrame Object will convert Header into Dictionary key.

e.g;-

```
df = pd.read_csv(fname)
df['ColumnName']


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as rdm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math as m

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', delimiter = ',',na_values="nan")

print(df['LOCATIONID']) # Gives you Columns Data for 'LOCATIONID'
print(df['LOCATION'])
```

Comment: By fname do you mean the name of the file. Also, if I have the column names as my first line separated by a comma, creating a DataFrame object automatically creates a dictionary?

Comment: yes name of the file, yes rather calling pandas.read_csv will return you Dataframe object by column names. you can specify delimiter like I shown you in example

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zip`:

```
import csv
headers = ['LOCATIONID', 'LOCATION', 'X', 'Y', 'LAT', 'LNG', 'REF', 'ID']
with open('filename.csv') as f:
  data = [dict(zip(headers, i)) for i in csv.reader(f)]

final_results = {i:[c[i] for c in data] for i in headers}
```

---

```
import json
print(json.dumps(final_results, indent=4))
```

Output:

```
{
"LOCATIONID": [
    "ChIJWzKeTARawokRjoqe_C9poOA",
    "ChIJDaBbDPlZwokRuHXkJGK9ER0",
    "ChIJQX6hfdlZwokRoCdPrD-8wSY",
    "ChIJi3MPPNNZwokRDu8nE0ldrwk",
    "ChIJq35iOdNZwokRKvT9_KFP8jg",
    "ChIJ07hkOtNZwokRfY7FzKrxTkA",
    "ChIJnYuB1ixYwokR3w26K1mr3JQ",
    "ChIJk7Y29CxYwokRLcD4dsTPCCM",
    "ChIJsZ2B5CxYwokRL8NrRMKxD9Q",
    "ChIJ64dzUNRZwokRIHBPnvi-eJs",
    "ChIJWexh_9hZwokRgU6sf8pvbUg",
    "ChIJRaQT-CxYwokRlEhCGnjf6fs",
    "ChIJFU-XRyxYwokRo5Do2LLO_mE"
],
"LOCATION": [
    "THEGIRLSOUTFITS",
    "NYNJ State Line",
    "Shipyard Marina",
    "Lincoln Harbor",
    "Lincoln Harbor",
    "852858 Harbor Blvd",
    "1500 Harbor Blvd",
    "800816 Waterfront Terrace",
    "Estuary Marketplace",
    "Estuary Apartments",
    "Hoboken Weehawken Notary Public  Dorian Cattani",
    "EcoPure Home Cleaning Service Weehawken",
    "New Jersey 495"
],
"X": [
    "0",
    "0",
    "0",
    "0",
    "0",
    "0",
    "0",
    "0",
    "0",
    "0",
    "0",
    "0",
    "0"
],
"Y": [
    "17",
    "29",
    "59",
    "68",
    "68",
    "68",
    "69",
    "71",
    "71",
    "71",
    "71",
    "72",
    "73"
],
"LAT": [
    "40.71380629999999",
    "40.7245721",
    "40.751581",
    "40.759708",
    "40.75984079999999",
    "40.7599265",
    "40.7609258",
    "40.7629756",
    "40.7622809",
    "40.76240009999999",
    "40.762501",
    "40.76302460000001",
    "40.76429109999999"
],
"LNG": [
    "-74.0222972",
    "-74.02168689999999",
    "-74.021287",
    "-74.02225",
    "-74.0223211",
    "-74.02213569999999",
    "-74.02135559999999",
    "-74.0223474",
    "-74.021577",
    "-74.0216088",
    "-74.021528",
    "-74.0218549",
    "-74.0220365"
],
"REF": [
    "dc1885d8c12ac669e9de3a73fedfb08c40deefd3",
    "3d2cfc0a35b583760187c2369bb957b5a8cd9755",
    "5f5e1aa75a39ce1880085d5094694a9ceda1ff43",
    "a3192a26d0a5a779da702a7f871612992e26f606",
    "38ea8de2bbf6d8a710bec3104d180d71b3d00735",
    "29cfd2338edc10f94f5464b2fe152ab7bab3fca6",
    "ed57711af76a2534406a70f21d8a7119170b0f72",
    "727cf2af87d28ec3a45f11e76e0746acfbec03b0",
    "1b6c2bd55b1bbabe3aac0d1eb2153e812c1026fd",
    "8219ad9d883d8891a651bc35ff7bf7abe7c7b72a",
    "11be9c0505e8db6a7fcaea5fd4003d336b8667f2",
    "33800368abbf808a39da3e805c685b245e5baac4",
    "23e5baf02ae51b7aeaf94efa56624c064bdbb456"
],
"ID": [
    "CmRSAAAA4Mvy3PVnmnYQKIZg-VX9-UrnrhlwOs7YFeY40gdXw1JfuUeEZndlhWxoIdI2K0nt1voCQDg2mqUVKV6EBgOKMTrHjDsMHOy7MJYBCUWguzLroifP1UMWTYSfUJD6E6sMEhB3psbJCGcDh5iS1PHyX4k5GhRBXigoOyADpURVG3NG2bIqXJ2i_g",
    "CmRRAAAAN25LD8IWAiu8CAIFM2eMS7eJVReV_UHzmR6sbaRkhDlJgiX-wK0Xlb85hC1qmDkarwQrGoM2u60zfSMr1MxcyzMAg3UDgL6nYwwu3WgG1aNlbpiqR2HlLFlK5XhimqI4EhDrfqXHOxKeztoT01Aicp3hGhSETo6Pj7gTk-dajA0RWco1djlrVA",
    "CmRRAAAAp_VV6L2SQgnjC_TeMYRe_m2EYyjo_IdAOUqSeuRM9kbEMHSyguWco9jDV6rdYxk5s1E5s21BX0P7flWfK2LCegcKi1m_AOp2LuYtuzv0ql4-Jeq6-yx50Z180J9U4nrHEhAihnIm2i8MWwk7ATToiLBgGhR-w02BFnO9EGniCms-XWq00VrGOg",
    "CmRRAAAAGcYQNoc-WgRCwh3rlBzeEmlG_XQgk_coHa4qUpzWU_9DiDWnU8eLjhInrZqpR7nKibXc0dcZIYiZEb-ehKvIrF6OfbLGrpmbf47YNaofAebceKirPZ_g6jMsc-_dcITaEhAKqkWagpXbgd3CcQf8Rtz-GhQtzlAGJlP7gOzV2KfXRGFIF2ZbAA",
    "CmRRAAAASNnGG2MHHIDGcXfgH-8iWUQOEahJdMZz6dy24azZrqyXqEtMb_yP1MJRGMV6Cp6lX05MgU2vNIfHcOGBfXiG0yWU7Qe0-t9_Uhm7JxNuAOEge9ZaCwNlrtxuxr8xSYsJEhAkL9vA29DV4nReD4e85D1TGhTbZYRfvNNRZi5a3NMUA0gyMYoR_A",
    "CmRbAAAAdlTDQx7qWhNnvgDQ_1afttKRpJ_MzBULrJLNX0TFEwpvKTjCvCZoXfV1F0A_diKH5D8qDjjucrjUC3gV8iVxqOYoHRGYwifE2FSiVycUrjunQxiDYAd-C6Q7QOqswAomEhAewuH-Q09vSAW_hNbQ0AUOGhQqRXCRrgxc6EAl2xRv1Z73M4MMug",
    "CmRbAAAAbPsHkeqeX3cx5MdED0Ao6ic0PE56xhGMdda0zXolIU7KsPmgPbT1CjXfyZ0p4ws_GYgdORZB3qP0idFvWBtMpdYpXCq0VknITsvfAoNfwYXoccYGsP7QvfpBPb1oTnywEhDwyrKX9JiQkYx9YaIXhkOwGhRCtFkL2futi7BkUxo_dMYEtsWVWA",
    "CmRbAAAAzgEUAIfexip_ePX2VQ29-iZMDPe-5RA4aGhFRoDkEGHrTaUON7ZGyn1r16erRSWIAhESFzycoG4Rwuw4OijSlLjKfK3_HCvC4fkrX-d6I7g7ffkIotwc1KK77UkHPMz-EhBoESHGx4Ke3H9y6XfDt9iaGhSGqEI5BmtpMu4URYwFmrT-2npHWQ",
    "CmRSAAAAO_HAcE9pNnA6r0FDp1eVsfS6jVn31DxU_JhcZNACGz9kfI5xOPjTbgM77JhJLxZPJqLgO_AnNXIIyEQV_wqO5Pr-YWJaIyhCEYA8Ene36VXgQ_90NMQwa_HNJJnWywkpEhBYQL6JbpsO0FJcOawnw5-2GhRE_QU6uh-cP-RKArGSyfEE2cxL3A",
    "CmRSAAAA7t8RT2MVUpaxNWBPItFU3pTQwNqXDuRY28GxZ_cywaLqOFIJ7taeXDHvGg19Y0MoIerm94HrD0iZQ_iIyoUrCKueeUETgHUGf8LQJMl9mqu784B5iIIXdf9-YrylAFJ9EhCvaowPZkGZvaEVLENy8fywGhRSEtZOm86qEyOCksoFWNJp9L_daw",
    "CmRRAAAA9hteDDXN0TehPTxfnx6LxRjZTVHZOyOgbE1GJ42XOzB2v6htFgfliFz39e6llMHSlqvFS3uBiIKuH9bNu9qIfeSD8LlrSW5UXKP4U7sN-Zi1-IWH5QJw5S2hQCZHaNfeEhAT4Y9Q2hC0uG0vVi7CJPuVGhQPb5J4VpGisRfvRfiqEyPgTR8F5w",
    "CmRSAAAAyod24y6jY17fcd2b2mk6qgIoN_KWOCNxEN1zDniW9n7RHoWTm-MPXFN6N77XwYzORC-WarFmyP9jULhochuKcXcYP2y2ni7SWFviXVXOBtxvYVlHmfsyHctEvBy_GxKbEhB5ihU8my5kq4lQpQrwGIrQGhT-0cYHqRnMImt55xhU7CBDPPlA1w",
    "CmRbAAAA_30BmNHIeCFJ7SVhLHWIbSa8llsfKQfYpVRC8X0feMrRlQ9ih9_vKtBfq-KRC6lcagEYQCBRdCfDob2divgzQEbrVkc9dR4v3oIfdyc5l9mlRyTnl1fOBxSeR8xMz78sEhD8FAIlIOza3aIMvqsdfjzrGhTj2R00Cv-lzmKIFEwLumKKd8g1cQ"
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read each row into a dictionary using [`csv.DictReader()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader):

```
import csv

fieldnames = ['LOCATIONID', 'LOCATION', 'X', 'Y', 'LAT', 'LNG', 'REF', 'ID']

with open('data.csv') as in_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(in_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    for row in csv_reader:
        # print out row info
        # e.g. row['LOCATION']
```

Which basically maps each row to a [`collections.OrderedDict()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), which is just an ordered dictionary.

If you want to map the row information to a final dictionary, you can use a [`collections.defaultdict()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

fieldnames = ['LOCATIONID', 'LOCATION', 'X', 'Y', 'LAT', 'LNG', 'REF', 'ID']

row_map = defaultdict(list)
with open('data.csv') as in_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(in_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    for row in csv_reader:
        for field in row:
            row_map[field].append(row[field])
```